# Map Hiera value to another value

Tags: puppet, hiera

How can I achieve something like this in Hiera?

```
service::enabled: true

plugin:
  sensu:
    ensure: (if service::enabled: 'present' else 'absent')
```

I know I can do this with `puppet` but would like to avoid that.

Comment: actually, you should do this. As the `data` is not a driven by the `model`, otherwise you get circular abstraction dependency. If you need this kind of logic, use a `profile::sensu`, and the profile can have the `if` logic.

Answer (score 1):

If you really, really (see below why you don't want to do this) want to have conditional logic in your data, then you could use my `tahu::ppyaml()` hiera backend which allows you to have puppet logic embedded in the yaml data, or write your own specific backend function. The tahu module requires Puppet 6. For versions of puppet before Hiera 5 you need to write a hiera 3 backend to achieve something similar. With Hiera 5 a backend function is very simple and can even be written in the puppet language.

You can find the tahu::ppayaml function here:
https://github.com/hlindberg/tahu/blob/master/lib/puppet/functions/tahu/ppyaml_key.rb

Your data would then look like this:

```
service::enabled: true

plugin:
  sensu:
    ensure: "if $service::enabled { 'present'} else {'absent'}"
```

Since the ppyaml backend treats every string as puppet language you need to quote all literal strings in the data file read by ppyaml; for example `"'foo'"` or `'"foo"'`.

You can however break out the key with a conditional into a separate file and use and alias in your main data file. Like this:

```
service::enabled: true

plugin:
  sensu:
    ensure: '%{alias("sensu::ensure")}'
```

And then, either using the `tahu::ppyaml` to bind only dynamic keys:

```
sensu::ensure: if $service::enabled { 'present'} else {'absent'}"
```

and adding that to your hiera.yaml referencing tahu::ppyaml as a backend.
It would work the same way if you write your own backend.

If any of this is recommended is a different question as it is questionable to have conditional logic in the data that depends on a variable being set or not in a manifest as you will get one value if you do the lookup before the inclusion of `sensu` and a different value after - and you are probably looking up the hash for the very purpose of declaring `sensu`.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Hiera doesn't have expressions that can do anything as sophisticated as conditional logic.

There are some aliasing and lookup functions, so you may be able to pass the value `service::enabled` through unmodified, but that is it. The functions in Hiera are documented at https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/latest/hiera_merging.html.